# Bash loop over a find result and get types of items found

Tags: bash, find

I have some code:

```
for item in $MYPATH
do
if [[ -f $item ]] ; then       #finds all files
    FILECOUNT=$[$FILECOUNT+1]
elif [[ -d $item ]] ; then     #finds all folders
    DIRCOUNT=$[$DIRCOUNT+1]
elif [[ -l $item ]] ; then     #supposed to find all symlinks
    SYMCOUNT=$[$SYMCOUNT+1]
fi
done
```

When I run it with just the file and directory types, it works fine, and gives me my counts.  But when I add in the `-l` if statement to count symlinks, it throws the following error:

```
conditional binary operator expected
syntax error near `$item'
`elif [[ -l $item ]] ; then'
```

I have no idea what's wrong.  Does anyone know?

Comment: That's `-L`, not `-l`

Comment: See: `help test`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-l` does not test for symbolic links. Use `-h` or `-L`.

You can use `-L` (or `-h`, it is equivalent) with either `[[...]]` or with `[...]`.

- The advantage of `[[ -L $item ]]` is that you may leave `$item` unquoted.
- While it needs double-quotes for `$item`, the advantage of `[ -L "$item" ]` is that it is POSIX and therefore highly portable.